# How to auto trigger a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, multibranch-pipeline

I'm using the [multi branch plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin) in Jenkins.
I'm using on-premise bitbucket and on-premise Jenkins who can talk to each other.

Now I can scan the repo and for every branch I get a Jenkins job (which uses a Jenkinsfile from the repository. It works okay the only thing is that the job or scanning is not triggered when I perform a new commit.

I've created a webhook in bitbucket using:

```
https://URL/jenkins/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify
```

But I receive a 400. (I'm able to use this type of hooks for normal Jenkins jobs/pipelines). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We also struggled with the setup of reliant webhooks with Jenkins & Bitbucket combo. In the end we settled with "Webhook to Jenkins for Bitbucket Server" from Mohami https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211284/webhook-to-jenkins-for-bitbucket?hosting=server&tab=overview

It's $$$ payware but integration & UI is flawless. -> well spent money